# Getting blank value while using Map

Tags: trigger

I'm practicing on creating a Trigger (still many things to learn...)

I would like to know on why am I getting a blank value on **Text__c**, the record's email address is an email address of an exisiting User.

See code snippet below.

```
trigger AutoChangeOwner on Contact (before insert, before update) {

Set<String> conEmail = new set<String>();
Map<String, Id> UsrMap = new map<String, Id>();

for(Contact con : trigger.new ){
    conEmail.add(con.Email);
    system.debug('conemail' + conEmail);
}

List<User> userEmail = [SELECT Id, Name, Email FROM User WHERE Email != null];
for(User u : userEmail){
    if(conemail.contains(u.email)){
        UsrMap.put(u.Email, u.Id); 
        system.debug('useremail' + userEmail);
    }
}

for(Contact c : trigger.new){
    c.Text__c = UsrMap.get(c.Email);
}

}
```

Any kind of explanation or ways to enhance the code is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the comments point out (I can't comment so I cant explain there) You're comparing a String (`u.email`) and a Set (`conemail`) these to things cannot be equal as one is a single string and one is a Set of strings. You just need to check if the String is *in* the Set. You can do this using `contains(value)` so if you replace `if(u.email == conemail)` with `if(conemail.contains(u.email))` it should solve your problem

Comment: thank you for your response. I've update my IF statement and even tried to comment the IF statement and still the field is not updating. I also tried to generate a debug log and I'm not able to see traces of `useremail`

Comment: So even without an If statement the `system.debug('useremail' + useremail);` line is not executing? You could add a check to see the size of your user email list before entering the loop just as a sanity check. Also try checking the emails are exactly the same eg no capitals as this may cause contains() to fail

Comment: I'm getting null assignment to Text__c 

Debug log results: `|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[21]|this.Text__c|null|0x2238376b `

Comment: Yes the null assignment will happen if a contact in the trigger does not have a corresponding user in the usr map collection so check how many users are in that map. The more system.debugs you have the more you'll know about how the code is running so try logging what is going on with the individual users and contact records

Comment: this.userEmail has 35 results because I removed the IF statement.

Comment: Ok, so It must be entering the loop that means either the `usrmap` is not getting populated or there's a problem with the contact loop and retrieving the email from the user map. Also do you mind updating the code in your question to the most recent you're running.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `system.debug('conemail' + conEmail);` after the first loop to see if you're populating the set correctly.

Then check if the list userEmail has been populated correctly with `system.debug('useremail' + userEmail);`

Comment: I'm getting the correct output from **conemail**.

In **useremail** I wasn't able to see any traces from the debug log. 

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't think you should use  `In: ConEmail` as a filter here, you should filter your SOQL based on an id set.

You can get users with non blank email fields with SQOL and loop inside collection to fill the UsrMap instead.

Comment: See my code update, how can I compare the **u.email** and **conemail**

I'm having an error: **Comparison arguments must be compatible types: String, Set<String>**

I'm getting the logic but I don't know how to convert it to code...

Comment: one of them is a set, one of them is a string value, you need to iterate over the set and check if the value of the member of the set equals your **u.email.**

Comment: Can you please provide sample on how should I do it? I really appreciate your help here!

Answer (score 0):

Your if-statement `if(u.email == conemail)` will always return `false`, so your `UsrMap` will always stay empty.

And doing the `.get()` on a map with an non-existing key will always return you `null`.

I would recommend changing that comparison to:

```
if(conemail.contains(u.email)) {
    // fill in your map here
}
```

Comment: thank you for your response. I've update my IF statement and even tried to comment the IF statement and still the field is not updating. I also tried to generate a debug log and I'm not able to see traces of `useremail`

Comment: To add up I'm getting null assignment to Text__c

`|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[21]|this.Text__c|null|0x2238376b`